# How can i write this Java code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to write this (Java) in Python?

```
class Test
{
  private String test1 = "test";
  private static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("test" + test1);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't have private stuff in python. The closest you can get to it is [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers)

Comment: Actually your example won't even compile, since `test1` is an instance variable and `main` is a static function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Python supports code outside of classes, the equivalent is as simple as:

```
test1 = "test"
print("test" + test1)
```

---

**UPDATE**: To get the args:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

You really should start with [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)!

Comment: But how do i get the args[] in your example? like in mine i can $ java -jar Test.jar "command line input"

Comment: Well you're example did not use args.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, like this:

```
test1 = "test"
print "test" + test1
```

But if you are using Python 3 you must write `print("test" + test1)`.